# Can I deploy multiple controllers in LXD on a single host?

Tags: juju, lxd, container

I wondering if there are possibilities to deploy 2 charms in 2 lxd containers on 2 different lxd controllers bootstrapped in the same localhost pc. I know this procedure could be useless but i want to play for better understanding, juju controllers and models management.

Could be this possible ? How to expose a charms inside different models to get a relation for exemple ?

Thanks for  any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest LXD containers..

So create two containers Huba and Buba  using

```
lxc launch ubuntu:20.10 Buba -c security.nesting=true
lxc launch ubuntu:20.10 Buba -c security.nesting=true
```

Now each of the containers can create its own containers but they will be isolated from each other or other containers at the same level..